# Python 2.7.10: Using LAMBDA and LOGICAL operators in DICT to choose a case

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, switch-statement

I am just fighting with some code and would need your help!

Objective:

- NOT using an IF-statement
- Choose a case and do something depending on the case
- No Python SWITCH because Python 2.7.10 is used!

Here is THE NOT YET functioning code --> depending on the value NBINS it should choose a certain function or do a calculation directly (e.g. `lambda x: x==nbins: bucket-=1`)

```
   def caseSwitcherCheckBucket(bucket):

        choose = {
            lambda x: x==nbins: maxBucket,
            lambda x: x<nbins: defaultBucket,
            }

        func = choose.get(bucket)
        return func()


    def defaultBucket(bucket):
        print 'defaultBucket():', bucket
        return bucket

    def maxBucket(bucket):          
        bucket-=1
        print 'maxBucket():', bucket
        return bucket
```

I found an example here: [Python dictionary instead of switch/case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222859/python-dictionary-instead-of-switch-case) and wanted to do what Dave Webb was suggesting. Here his code:

```
values = {
    lambda x: x < 4: foo,
    lambda x: x > 4: bar
}
```

Unfortunately it is not working in this case! **How can I fix this?**

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Normally I use this kind of "CaseSwitcher" --> here is an example!

```
   def caseSwitcherCheckLogStatus(check_log_status):

        choose = {
            True: entLog,               
            False: doNothing,
            }

        func = choose.get(check_log_status)
        return func()

    def entLog():
        data[i,[0,1,2]] = 10**(data[i,[0,1,2]])

    def doNothing():
        pass
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

**If you have any idea how I can improve my "CaseSwitcher" in general I am also very happy to get some advice.**

Comment: No version of Python has a switch statement, and there is no, and never will be, a version 2.10.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo --> I am using 2.7.10!  And, OK, I understood that wrong, I thought Python 3.0 has one. I am new in the field.

Comment: "NOT using an IF-statement" is a silly restriction. It keeps you from having an `else` and, therefore, you will have either difficult-to-read code or logical holes of unhandled cases.

Comment: @dawg: Hello, correct me if I am wrong but I think the IF-statements in a loop is slowing down my programme. I recognized that and therefore I wanted to get rid of them in a big loop, however, using them everywhere else ...

Comment: *I think the IF-statements in a loop is slowing down my program.* Really? What makes you think that?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I am not sure about that, I do not understand enough of this matter to give a qualified answer. I just recognized that my calculations last longer when I am using an IF-statement in every loop (0 < i < 400 Mill)  instead of one of my "caseSwitchers". Maybe it is just a coincidence and the time depends on something else. I will test it and I am also curious about what will be the best option for me. But I am running out of time and I have to fix that, so I have to ask and get down voted!

Comment: You cannot say "*I am new in the field*" and then go on about "*I think <...> is slowing down my program*". Leave optimization for later, start by doing good readable code. Most often than not, good readable "Pythonic" code is quite fast, or at least, very easy to optimize.

Comment: If performance is your consideration, `if` is the wrong target. For your lamba dict to work, you will need to loop through every key and call the function -- not an improvement over `if`

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it like this:

```
def switcher(cases, default_func=None):
    def switch(value):
        for case_func, result in cases:
            if case_func(value):
                return result(value)

        if default_func is not None:
            return default_func(value)
        else:
            raise RuntimeError("No case matched and no default given")

    return switch
```

Usable as

```
my_switch = switcher([
    (lambda value: value == nBins, maxBucket),
    (lambda value: value < nBins, defaultBucket),
])

my_switch(val)
```

Comment: Since performance was mentioned by the questioner in comments, I have to point out that this will be slower than the equivalent `if: else:` construct, due to the additional function calls it entails.

Comment: That's pretty much guaranteed, yes :)

Comment: @filmor: Thanks for helping, but I would need the quickest way. I asked this question because I wanted to test if my programme is faster not using IF-statements all the time.